# Trying to get the longest decreasing substring from a given string, keeping the case sensitivity in mind

Tags: python-3.x, longest-substring

I have been trying to get below result out of this Program but for some reason it is not giving the required output.

Required Results:

`Input1 : bbaasssrppoccbaaacbaba    Output1 : ['bbaa','sssrppoccbaaa','cba','ba']`
`Input2: hjgAvjhjKLhbfvbZSF    Output2 :['h', 'jgA', 'vjh', 'jK', 'L', 'hb', 'f','vbZSF']`

What i am getting

`Output: ['bbaa', 'sssrppoccbaaa', 'cba']` & `Output: ['h', 'jgA', 'vjh', 'jK', 'L', 'hb', 'f']` from below code which is not getting last substring `"ba" & "vbZSF"`.

```
s1 = 'bbaasssrppoccbaaacbaba'
# s1 = 'hjgAvjhjKLhbfvbZSF'


decSub = ''
listSub = []
i= 0

while i < len(s1):
    current = s1[i]
    previous = s1[i] if i == 0 else s1[i-1]
    if ord(current) <= ord(previous):
        decSub += current
    else:
        listSub.append(decSub)

        decSub = ''
        decSub += current
    i +=1
print(listSub)
```

It would be great if somebody could suggest a fix or a better way to achieve this result.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to append the missing `decSub` in the list.

**Updated Code:**

```py
s1 = 'bbaasssrppoccbaaacbaba'
# s1 = 'hjgAvjhjKLhbfvbZSF'


decSub = ''
listSub = []
i= 0

while i < len(s1):
    current = s1[i]
    previous = s1[i] if i == 0 else s1[i-1]
    if ord(current) <= ord(previous):
        decSub += current
    else:
        listSub.append(decSub)
        decSub = ''
        decSub += current

    i += 1

listSub.append(decSub)

print(listSub)
```

**Output:**

```
# s1 = 'bbaasssrppoccbaaacbaba'
['bbaa', 'sssrppoccbaaa', 'cba', 'ba']

# s1 = 'hjgAvjhjKLhbfvbZSF'
['h', 'jgA', 'vjh', 'jK', 'L', 'hb', 'f', 'vbZSF']
```

Comment: If it resolves your issue then please accept this answer and give an upvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

`while` loop is better choice for iterations without arbitrary boundaries - in your case `for` loop is probably a better choice.

Try the following instead:

```py
from typing import List

def split_special(txt: str) -> List[str]:
    if len(txt) == 0:
        return []
    res = [txt[0]]
    prev = ord(txt[0])
    for l in map(ord, txt[1:]):
        if prev >= l:
            res[-1] += chr(l)
        else:
            res.append(chr(l))
        prev = l
    return res
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> print(Input1)

bbaasssrppoccbaaacbaba

>>> print(split_special(Input1))

['bbaa', 'sssrppoccbaaa', 'cba', 'ba']

>>> print(Input2)

hjgAvjhjKLhbfvbZSF

>>> print(split_special(Input2))

['h', 'jgA', 'vjh', 'jK', 'L', 'hb', 'f', 'vbZSF']
```

Comment: Thanks @Grzegorz, this is more refined.